# making large csv chartable by querying iso code in highcharts

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, highcharts

I'm trying to load a csv and format it so it will display as a chart in highcharts, this is proving difficult because of the structure of the csv data.

Here is the csv: https://pastebin.com/Ynz7GJJh

Sample:

```
iso,type,year,affected
JAM,Earthquake,1907,90000
JAM,Storm,1912,94820
TON,Volcano,1946,2500
DZA,Earthquake,1954,129250
HTI,Storm,1954,250000
```

Here is my highcharts.ajax so far

```
var hsOptions = {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'KEY NATURAL HAZARD STATISTICS'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Number of People Affected'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: []
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Units'
        }
    },
    series: []
};

Highcharts.ajax({
    url: '/pathto.csv',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(csv) {
            var rows = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);
            var cell;
            var series = [];
            var seriesBuilder = {name: countryValue, data: []};
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                cell = rows[i].split(',');
                if (cell[0] === countryValue){
                    seriesBuilder.data.push(cell);
                }
            }
        console.log(seriesBuilder);
        series.push(seriesBuilder);
        hsOptions.series.push(series);
        Highcharts.chart('hazard-stats', hsOptions);

    },
    error: function (e, t) {
        console.error(e, t);
    }
});
```

which does make this

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0p6a1sp7mclv4ta/chrome_2018-06-20_08-58-43.png?dl=0]

But I need this to build a series per disaster type, then the years have to combine on their own axis... it should be able to render just like this:

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kjtsw6edddmw4j6/chrome_2018-06-20_09-01-45.png?dl=0]

Comment: Always include code in your text, not as an image. Especially not an image hosted on dropbox. It makes it annoying to figure out what you are trying to do. That said, is this the graph you are hoping to end up with: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/30Lpcm5x/8/?

Comment: Good to know, I simply wrapped your code with this to ensure it's only dealing with the loaded country, works great, thank you!
`if (cell[0] === countryValue){}`